# Why doesn't my bmp save with transparent background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg, transparency, bmp

I have the following `.bmp` file called `mapa.bmp`

[image]

As you can see, from the embedded picture, my background is fully transparent.
I made sure to check and my `Image->Mode` is set to `RGB` as well.

[image]

and I saved it using the default options:

[image]

All seems fine and dandy, right?

However, if I use the picture anywhere, or even re-open it with photoshop, the transparent background is lost and opened with white background.

[image]

> Saving the file as `.png` works fine, but sadly I need to use `.bmp`, `.ico` or `.jpg` format

Any idea what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the duplicate question, while `.bmp` supports
transparency - technically - it is not entirely recommended to.

> In case you can't use `.png` (like I couldn't), it's best to use
>   `.jpeg 2000` or `.gif` format as a substitute